# How to make a owl carousel with arrows instead of next previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Yesterday I presented a website to a customer. I always use Owl carousel since it's responsive. The client, however, hated the previous, next words, and wanted to change them to arrows.

So hence I updated my script. js file. It was very easy to do and I wanted to share it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
     ...
 })
 $( ".owl-prev").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>');
 $( ".owl-next").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
});
```

Well there you have it. You can always add more styling. (First time I use an answer to your own question hope this is the right place/way)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how you do it in your `$(document).ready()` function with FontAwesome Icons:

```
 $( ".owl-prev").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>');
 $( ".owl-next").html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>');
```

Answer (score 63):

If you're using `Owl Carousel 2`, then you should use the following:

```
$(".category-wrapper").owlCarousel({
     items : 4,
     loop  : true,
     margin : 30,
     nav    : true,
     smartSpeed :900,
     navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"]
   });
```

Answer (score 27):

**Complete tutorial** [**here**](https://www.freakyjolly.com/owl-carousel-2-customize-navigation-next-prev-arrows/)

**Demo** [**link**](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/jquery/OwlCarousel2/)

[image]

**JavaScript**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    navText:["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide'></div>","<div class='nav-btn next-slide'></div>"],
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
        },
        600: {
            items: 3
        },
        1000: {
            items: 5
        }
    }
});
```

**CSS Style for navigation**

```
.owl-carousel .nav-btn{
  height: 47px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 100px !important;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-prev.disabled,
.owl-carousel .owl-next.disabled{
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 0.2;
}

.owl-carousel .prev-slide{
  background: url(nav-icon.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  left: -33px;
}
.owl-carousel .next-slide{
  background: url(nav-icon.png) no-repeat scroll -24px 0px;
  right: -33px;
}
.owl-carousel .prev-slide:hover{
 background-position: 0px -53px;
}
.owl-carousel .next-slide:hover{
background-position: -24px -53px;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

A note for others who may be using Owl Carousel v 1.3.2:

You can replace the navigation text in the settings where you're enabling the navigation.

```
navigation:true,
navigationText: [
   "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>",
   "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"
]
```

Comment: if you're looking at owl carousel 2 they changed the option names navigation to nav and navigationText to navText

Answer (score 17):

If you using latest Owl Carousel 2 version. You can replace the Navigation text by fontawesome icon. Code is below.

```
$('.your-class').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        items: 1, // Select Item Number
        autoplay:true,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        navText: ["<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i>"],

    });
```

Answer (score 16):

The following code works for me on **owl carousel** .

https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"]
});
```

For **OwlCarousel2**

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

```
 $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    nav: true,
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"]
});
```