# Owl Carousel "navText:" doesn't add arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I want to add arrows to my carousel. I've searched for solutions for my answer, copied the code, but somehow it did not work.

So, I've this HTML:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
            <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
            <source src="fleuropdemo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="video-wrapper">
                <p>FLEUR OP / BEZORGT EEN GOED GEVOEL</p>
                <h2>HET GEVOEL VAN BLOEMEN ANDERS VERTELD</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
   ...2 more .item
</div>
```

These are the files I have in my html: `owl.carousel.css, owl.theme.default.min.css, owl.carousel.js, jquery.min.js``

And this is what I'm doing in my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

 navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
 nav: true,
 navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
 loop: true,
 slideSpeed : 300,
 paginationSpeed : 400,

 items : 1, 
 itemsDesktop : false,
 itemsDesktopSmall : false,
 itemsTablet: false,
 itemsMobile : false

});

});
```

The navText solution I have from this post: [How to make a owl carousel with arrows instead of next previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605932/how-to-make-a-owl-carousel-with-arrows-instead-of-next-previous/34912034)

What I want to achieve is exactly the same. But somehow the solution doesn't work for me...

I've also tested multiple codepens, exactly copied their code. Did not work. I'm starting to think I'm missing files. I'm using the latest version for owl carousel.

The rest of the carousel works perfectly.

Comment: Check your console if there are any errors

Comment: Nope, no errors in console.

Comment: What's not working exactly? Slider is there only navigation not showing? Or slider not working at all?

Comment: The slider itself is working. It's just the the chevron's aren't showing.

Comment: Do you have fontawesome installed correctly?

Comment: I had it installed. But tried it again in another index file.

I've put the font-awesome on top now, this fixed it! Thanks :)

Comment: Created answer for this, for future people which can open this question. Please mark it as correct result. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icon's are not displaying because font awesome isn't correctly installed.